# Hermitian conjugation and representations of the Lorentzian Clifford algebras

Tags: representation-theory, physics, mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras

The Clifford algebra $\mathcal{C}\ell _{1,2d-1}$ is central and simple ([L](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~amt/amt2.pdf)), and hence has a unique faithful, irreducible representation (over $\mathbb{R}$) ([A](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~amt/amt2.pdf)).  Denote this representation by $\gamma :\mathcal{C}\ell _{1,2d-1}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$, for some complex vector space $V$, let $e_0,\ldots ,e_{2d-1}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{C}\ell _{1,2d-1}$, and define $\gamma ^\mu :=\gamma (e_\mu )$.

I have been told that we may always choose the $\gamma$ matrices so that
$
(\gamma ^\mu )^*=\gamma _\mu=\begin{cases}(-\gamma ^0,\vec{\gamma}) & \text{for signature }(-,+,\cdots ,+) \\ (\gamma ^0,-\vec{\gamma}) & \text{for signature }(+,-,\cdots ,-)\end{cases},
$
where $^*$ denotes the Hermitian conjugate.

($\vec{\gamma}=(\gamma ^1,\ldots ,\gamma ^{2d-1})$ is the spatial part of $\gamma ^\mu$.)

How does one show that there is always a representation in the equivalence class of the given $\gamma$ that satisfies this property?  (To be clear, I was only told this to be true in the case relevant for physics, i.e. $d=2$, but presumably it is true in general).

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing the notation. Since $\gamma$ is a representation of the Clifford algebra, it looks like $(\gamma^\mu)^\ast$ is a Hermitian conjugate (maybe). The braces with two ordered pairs kind of looks like a matrix, but I have no idea how to interpret an ordered pair consisting of a matrix and the reresentation $\gamma$. Can you help us read this a little?

Comment: @rschwieb I edited the post in an attempt to make my notation more lucid.  Please let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: OK, that helps a bit, although I still have a question. I can see now that the ordered pair of gammas consists of the coordinate that's of different signature from the rest, which you are lumping together into a single vector. Does that sound right?

Comment: @rschwieb If I understand you correctly, then yes, that is right.  I edited the post again to further clarify.  Let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's clear enough to think about now :)

Comment: Still stuck. $\gamma(e_\mu)\in M_n(\Bbb C)$, but I still had the feeling you meant for $\gamma^0$ to be a number in $\Bbb C$. It's possible that there's a natural interpretation that makes that work, but I thought I'd bring it up and see what you thought about it.

Comment: No.  $\gamma ^0$ is supposed to be an $2^d\times 2^d$ matrix with complex entries.  (I might have screwed up the dimension, but it is definitely a matrix of the same dimension as $\gamma ^i$ for $i\geq 1$.)

Comment: And so $\vec{\gamma}$ is $2^d\times 2^d(2^d-1)$?

Comment: $\vec{\gamma}$ is a collection of $2d-1$ matrices ($\gamma ^1$ through $\gamma ^{2d-1}$) of dimension $2^d\times 2^d$.